# Connecting to mongoDB from an NPM package

Tags: javascript, mongodb, npm, node-modules

I'll try to make this quick, would anyone happen to know a way to connect to MongoDB from an NPM package? I've been researching a viable option but haven't really found anything concrete. Mongoose does not seem to be working, I get mongoose.connect is not a function, but this makes sense as I'm not running a node/express server.

**Error Message (Browser Console)**

```
warn @ webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:620
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1887 TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function
 at Object.getPrivateChain (webpack-internal:///../iotapp-api/index.js:17)
...
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
import dtapp from "dtapp-api" //Linked NPM module

...

mounted () {

dtapp.getPrivateData();

}
```

**index.js (NPM package)**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = {
  getPrivateData() {
    mongoose.connect(
      "mongodb+srv://<myusername>:<mypassword>@cluster0-76qng.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
      function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success");
        }
      }
    );
  }
};
```

I guess my question would also be if mongoose is a no-go, are there any alternatives that would allow me to connect and query the DB? Realm (AKA Stitch) looks promising, but I'm not sure if even this would be possible, maybe there is someone who could offer insight? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean you're not running node? npm is the package manager for node env so you pretty much have to install node.

Comment: I understand but you can use NPM to develop for just the front-end too, I only meant I have no backend server.js type file running in my env 0_o